Apache FOP for .NET Core (FOP.NetCore v. 3.0): Wingdings 2/3 not found
Our organization switched to using C# Apache FOP.NetCore 3.0 .NET library to generate PDF documents recently. Shortly after the switch, we discovered that we can not use "Wingdings 2" and "Wingdings 3" TTFs in the generated PDF documents. However, we can use "Wingdings" (the "first" TTF version).
We do not get any error message, but the generated PDFs do not contain any Wingdings 2 / 3 symbols. Instead, in place of Wingdings 2 it uses empty boxes.
I tried multiple ways to define "Wingdings 2" font-family using XSL-FO. Few of the examples:

<fo:block font-family="Wingdings 2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font-family="Wingdings2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font-family="Wingdings_2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font-family="Wingdings Wingdings 2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font-family="Wingdings Wingdings2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font-family="Wingdings Wingdings_2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font="Wingdings 2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font="Wingdings2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font="Wingdings_2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font="Wingdings Wingdings 2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font="Wingdings Wingdings2">...</fo:block>
<fo:block font="Wingdings Wingdings_2">...</fo:block>
...

In the XML Files, which are used to define PDF documents using XSL-FO (XSL Formatting Objects), we can without problems use Wingdings TTF (but not Wingings 2 or 3).
Wingdings 2 / 3 TTFs are properly installed in my OS (Windows 10), and I can use them in another applications (ex. MS Word 2019).
Have you had similar experience and would you know, please, how to properly specify "Wingdings 2" string to appear in a .pdf file using XSL-FO? Thanks, many times.
I expected seeing characters specific to Wingdings 2 in the generated .pdf document. Instead I got small rectangles for each character, meaning, the defined TTF/Font-Family has not been found.

Have a look at https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.9/configuration.html#renderers on how to use fonts in Apache Fop.

Check to see if the font is Unicode or now. Most non-Unicode fonts cannot be used.
